# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have been trying many different pieces of codes and continuously getting the same error. A simple code is posted as an example below where it returned the error of no attribute 'shape' . Kindly, point out what's  wrong with this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread ('fw1.jpg')
print img.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the return value of cv2.imread() is None, but why is it None?

Here are reasons possible:

1. the path of image is false, OpenCV won't notice you even if the path of image file doesn't exist
2. the lib opencv-python isn't installed, you can run the command 
   `pip install --upgrade opencv-python` to install the lib

Comment: Given that `import cv2` works, it's more likely that the path to the image is wrong than the OpenCV library isn't installed.

Comment: The path is appropriate because the image is right there at the desktop. I tried the upgrading and the problem still persists.

Comment: I tried executing the programs that were previously being executed. But now, those programs aren't even running. 
Should i re-install OpenCV library?

Comment: Can you try to use absolutely path with '/' replacing '\'?

Comment: Here may be another reason that you forget to compile OpenCV with JPEG file support enabled.For example, you have to install the ```jpeg``` library in macOS

Comment: Finally my code worked. There was some problem with the image path. 
Now, I am trying to execute this code and gives: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
"
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    x = np.random.randint(0,5,(500,500))
    img = cv2.imread('D:\Project\Capture1.jpg',0)
    p = img.shape
    print p
    rows,cols = img.shape

    for i in range(rows): 
        for j in range(cols):
            k = x[i,j]
             print k